Omitting adverbial clauses/prepositional phrases from positive degrees

Rana is as tall as rakin (is).

From this positive degree, can we omit as rakin (is)?
After omitting,

Rana is as tall.

In a context, for example:

A-- Is rana as tall as rakin (is)?


B-- yes, Rana is as tall.

Am I right or not?

I assume that Rakin is another person's name; if so, it should always be written with a capital letter.
You can omit is, but you can't omit as Rakin, unless it is clear from what someone has said earlier that Rana's and Rakin's heights are being compared. In the dialogue you quote, all that B needs to say is "Yes, she is", or even just "Yes".
